# Javascript Array value from server

Tags: javascript, arrays

how to send Array value from server?
If I send it like this:
"a","b","c"
then in JavaScript (after GET and Alert) I have only "a", for example:

```
$.get('xx', function(labels){
  alert(labels);  // <- here I have only "a"
});
```

how to receive all 3 values from server?
Thanks

OK it is solved using:
    JSON.parse(labels)
thanks to everybody!

Comment: which server side language you use.?

Comment: If you were sending these values from client to server, then you would have to encode them with `encodeURIComponent` (javascript). I'm guessing that you have to do the same when you're sending them from server to client. In what language have you implemented your server?

Comment: what server side language?

Comment: Post your server side code.

Comment: give your server side code (.NET, PHP etc... )

Comment: You should format your array with JSON.

Comment: I'm using WeOnlyDo Webserver and VB code. If I use this: var labels = labels_data; it does not work (inside labels_data is ["a","b","c"] and it is send from server. If I use var labels = ["a","b","c"] (inside Javascript code, then it works ... Why client does not receive it just like server send it?? How to use JSON to send it from server? Thanks!

Comment: I mean, I know how to use JSON if I have this { "name":"a"} but I need to send only "a" without "name" !

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be done using pure javascript,you can do this.
Since you have not mentioned which server side language you using,I will show with JSP.

First store your array in a javascript variable.

```
var x=new Array();
x="<%=Serverarray%>"
```

This will give an output like this "[a,b,c]"

In order to retrieve values from the database you need to use x[0],x[1].....

```
x[0]=a;
x[1]=b;
x[2]=c;
```